# Listen to all "onClick" events from anchor tags that could possibly contain children

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, anchor, dom-events

I'm trying to implement a simple(-ish) router as an exercise. However, I'm having trouble detecting anchor clicks. Ideally, I'd like to intercept an event anytime the URL changes (without using hashes), but for now I just want to be able to intercept any anchor click event.

Here is what I've tried so far :

**HTML**

```
<nav id="mainMenu">
    <ul id="navlinks">
        <li>
            <a href="/">
                <span>HOME</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/posts">
                <span>POSTS</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Separate JS file**

```
function intercept(event)
{
    console.log("triggered");
    var tag = event.target;

    if (
        tag.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'A' &&
        tag.href &&
        event.button == 0 &&
        tag.origin == document.location.origin
    ){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("default prevented")
    }
}
```

With this code, I'm only detecting the `span` events, and not the `<a>` events. What can I do to detect the anchor click events using vanilla JS (if possible)? I want to be able to detect dynamically created anchors as well.

**EDIT 1:** Altered the JS function. Console prints `default prevented: SPAN`:

```
function intercept(event)
{
    console.log("triggered");
    var tag = event.target;

    //if (
    //    tag.tagName === 'A'
    //){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("default prevented: " + tag.tagName);
    //}
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Anchor tags will not always have children, and possible children may not be a `span`.

Comment: comment out some of your conditional predicates until it works as expected, then rework the condition.

Comment: To detect navigation attempts you can listen for beforeunload on the body.

Comment: @dandavis All of my conditionals are gone now. It still only detects span clicks.

Comment: @dtanders Would that let me prevent the page from unloading?

Comment: how are you binding the handler?

Comment: You can't stop the user from leaving your website, haha.

Comment: @ScottKaye I'm not trying to. I'm trying to implement a router for a single page web app. I only want to prevent unloads if the root of the address is the same.

Comment: @dandavis `document.addEventListener('click', intercept);`

Comment: ok, what do you see in the first console.log() call when clicking an A?

Comment: @dandavis `"triggered"`. I altered the second `console.log` to `console.log("default prevented: " + tag.tagName);`, and it outputs `"default prevented: SPAN"`

Comment: try `document.addEventListener('click', intercept, true);`

Comment: @dandavis same result.

Comment: @Guilmon, http://jsfiddle.net/swoe33oa/6/ does this help you?

Comment: event target is really span, so your condition for the tag name is A doesn't work. you need to compare target tag name with 'span' and check if target parent is `<a>`

Comment: @nevermind no, it doesn't: this assumes that an anchor tag will always have a span as it's child, which won't be true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need to do is "walk up the document tree" from the `event.target` element until you find an anchor tag.

The advantage of this solution is it utilizes event delegation and can be run at any point in the lifecycle of the page. The `document.documentElement` property is the `<html>` tag, and it exists the moment JavaScript begins executing.

```js
function findParentByTagName(element, tagName) {
    var parent = element;

    while (parent !== null && parent.tagName !== tagName.toUpperCase()) {
        parent = parent.parentNode;
    }

    return parent;
}

function handleAnchorClick(event) {
    event = event || window.event;

    if (findParentByTagName(event.target || event.srcElement, "A")) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("An anchor was clicked!");
    }
}

document.documentElement.addEventListener("click", handleAnchorClick, false);
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="#">
    <span>
      <b>
        <i>Click me!</i>
      </b>
    </span>
  </a>
</p>

<p>
  <a href="#">Click me too!</a>
</p>
```

Comment: I altered the code slightly so that I could access the anchor tag that was detected (assign result of `findParentByTargetName` to local variable). I can't shake the feeling that this is more of a workaround though. Maybe it just isn't possible at the moment.

Comment: This is the basic method for doing event delegation. All major JavaScript libraries or frameworks start at `event.target` and walk up the document tree until some condition is met. I created [Oxydizr](https://github.com/gburghardt/oxydizr), which is an event delegation library that you can plug into existing code. It is a little more robust than this solution, but I'm not sure if it will work for your single page app.

Answer (score 1):

Its because `event.target` will always point to the deepest possible node that was clicked.

`event.path` is essentially what you would need, but afaik its not widely implemented (yet).

Here is how to get an array of all the target's parents, like event.path would yield:

```
function getPath(e) {
  return e.parentElement? [e].concat(getPath(e.parentElement)) : [e];
}
```

Once you have that, you can test whether any of those elements is an anchor:

```
var thereIsAnAnchorInMyPath = getPath(event.target)
  .reduce(function(isAnchor, element) {
    return isAnchor || /^a$/i.test(element.tagName);
  }, false);
```

Your example would thus read:

```
function intercept(event){
    console.log("triggered");
    var thereIsAnAnchorInMyPath = (event.path || getPath(event.target))
      .reduce(function(isAnchor, element) {
        return isAnchor || /^a$/i.test(element.tagName);
      }, false);

    if (thereIsAnAnchorInMyPath){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("default prevented")
    }
}
```

Of course, it would be far easier to just attach the event listeners to the anchors:

```
[].slice.call(querySelectorAll('a')).forEach(function(anchor) {
  anchor.addEventListener('click', intercept);
});
```

But that would not work if (for some reason) new anchors were inserted into the document. In that case, you would need to attach an event listener to each new anchor, as soon as it gets inserted into the document.

Or you could listen to DOM mutation events and then query for all anchors, filter for those that you already have attached event listeners to, add them to a list (so you can filter for them in subsequent events) and finally attach event listeners.

Comment: This is a good solution, but I'm going to go with Greg Burghardt's answer, as it's easier to understand.